# How to return an array/list from an assembly to a stored procedure in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, .net-assembly, sqldatatypes

I have a stored procedure that accepts a string and extracts substrings that starts with '@'. I decided to use C# DLL for this and access this DLL using SQL Assemblies. So, I developed following method in C#:

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction]
public static ? GetSubStrings(string text)
{
       List<string> IDs=new List<string>();
       foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(text, @"(?<!\w)@\w+"))
       {
           try
           {
                IDs.Add(match.Value.Replace("@", ""));
           }
           catch (NullReferenceException) { continue; }
       }
       return IDs;
}
```

I added '?' sign in place of return type because I don't know what return type this method should return? Please tell me the solution. I am unable to find any SQL type that stores this kind of data.

Comment: when you step through the code with the debugger.. what is the value of `match` before executing this line `IDs.Add(match.Value.Replace("@", ""));` if `match contains @` then add a line above `IDs.Add(match.Value.Replace("@", ""));` and do `match = match.Replace("@", "")` then do `IDs.Add(match)`

Comment: @MethodMan This method is working fine but the problem is what should be the return type of my method when returned to a SQL stored procedure. The Regex code is not my problem.

Comment: It sure would be nice to see the stored procedure that way we can determine if it should be a DataTable, IEnumerable, String, Int., etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this you need to make your function a [Table Valued Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131103.aspx), this will make your function return a table instead of a single result. To do this you need to use the [`TableDefinition`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.server.sqlfunctionattribute.tabledefinition(v=vs.110).aspx) property and have your return type be a `IEnumerable`.

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction(TableDefinition="IDs nvarchar(max)"]
public static IEnumerable GetSubStrings(string text)
{
       List<string> IDs=new List<string>();
       foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(text, @"(?<!\w)@\w+"))
       {
           try
           {
                IDs.Add(match.Value.Replace("@", ""));
           }
           catch (NullReferenceException) { continue; }
       }
       return IDs;
}
```